# Taxonomy Child Not Updating Unless I Click Update Twice

Tags: custom-taxonomy, terms, save-post, wp-update-post

I am using code [from this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/173641/128837) to create a new child taxonomy term, however for some reason the change only takes effect if I click update post **twice**. Clicking Update Post once doesn't save the change.

Here is the code from the answer of the linked question.

```
add_action('save_post_cpt', 'run_on_update');

function run_on_update($post_id) {
// $_POST['input_name']; is an array
//get the array and sanitize it
$input_terms = array_map( 'sanitize_text_field', $_POST['input_name'] );
//Set the array of terms for later use on wp_set_object_terms
$terms = array();
foreach( $input_terms as $term ) {
    
    $existent_term = term_exists( $term, 'the_tax' );

    if( $existent_term && isset($existent_term['term_id']) ) {

        $term_id = $existent_term['term_id'];

    } else {

        //intert the term if it doesn't exsit
        $term = wp_insert_term(
            $term, // the term 
            'the_tax', // the taxonomy
            array(
                    'parent' => 3, // ID of parent tax term
                )
        );
        if( !is_wp_error($term ) && isset($term['term_id']) ) {
             $term_id = $term['term_id'];
        } 

   }

   //Fill the array of terms for later use on wp_set_object_terms
   $terms[] = (int) $term_id;

}

wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, $terms, 'the_tax' );
}
```

I did see [this answer about wp cache interfering](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/8921/128837), however according to the last answer on that post that issue was fixed years ago. (The solution there was to insert  `delete_option("{$taxonomy}_children");` right after the term is added, but even that doesn't work.

**Any help is greatly appreciated!**

Comment: You may want to look at the `pre_post_update` action instead of `save_post_` - looking at the way it's handled in the `wp_insert_post()` function, terms are updated before the actual call to the database. I haven't dug in but I'm wondering if WordPress does some house keeping for terms on the post before it fires the `save_post_` action, and you doing it after the fact isn't letting WP properly make those connections.

Comment: @phatskat Thanks for your reply! Unfortunately when I used the hook `pre_post_update` it didn't even save the change.